# Добавление/удаление элементов на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Помогите с решением задачи, всю голову уже сломал:)

В общем, есть 5 кнопок и блоки 4 классов, нужно при клике на кнопку скрывать 3 типа блоков, оставляя 1. Каждая кнопка показывает определенный класс блоков, а одна кнопка должна показать все блоки.

Comment: Можете скинуть пример кода или какие-то наработки? А то не совсем понятно
Если правильно Вас понимаю, то скрытие блоков будет по определенному классу по нажатию на определенную кнопку
Только какому блоку какие классы добавлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если я правильно понял задание, то как-то так:

```js
jQuery( "input[type=submit]" ).click(function() {
    jQuery("div").show();
    var get_value = jQuery(this).data("value");
    if(get_value == null){
        jQuery("div").show();
    }else{
        jQuery("."+get_value).hide();
    }
});
```

```css
div{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first second third">Первый блок</div>
<div class="first third fourth">Второй блок</div>
<div class="first second fourth">Третий блок</div>
<div class="second third fourth">Четвертый блок</div>
<input type="submit" value="Первая кнопка" data-value="first">
<input type="submit" value="Вторая кнопка" data-value="second">
<input type="submit" value="Третья кнопка" data-value="third">
<input type="submit" value="Четвертая кнопка" data-value="fourth">
<input type="submit" value="Отобразить все блоки">
```